# Binding ItemsSource to an EntityFramework ObjectSet<T> does not generate content

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Our application is in use of several TreeViewItem and DataGrid controls in XAML whose `ItemsSource` properties are bound to Entity Framework `ObjectSet<Entity>` collections. The problem is that the UI controls are behaving as if the ObjectSets are empty.

The EF `ObjectContext` is enclosed within a singleton class in a static class:

```
public static class BusinessData
{
    public static readonly BizDataSource Source = BizDataSource.Instance;
}

public class BizDataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BusinessEntitiesObjectContext _context = ...;
```

and the ObjectSets are being returned from readonly properties within the singleton:

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> RetiredEmployees
    {
        get { 
            return (from it in _context.Employees where it.Status == "Retired" select it);  
        }
    }
```

and finally, the ItemsSource is data bound to the collection, with INotifyPropertyChanged serving to update the UI when its known that the data source is updated:

```
<TreeViewItem x:Name="PART_TVI" Header="Retired Employees"
     ItemsSource="{Binding 
       Source={x:Static local:BusinessData.Source}, 
       Path=RetiredEmployees}" 
/>
```

Debug stepping has revealed that the binding is correctly providing an IEnumerable which resolves to the business objects, but it seems like the control isn't iterating upon it. For example, if I add this code to the window:

```
PART_TVI.ItemsSource = BusinessData.Source.RetiredEmployees;
```

The same behavior occcurs as with XAML Binding: nothing. However:

```
PART_TVI.ItemsSource = BusinessData.Source.RetiredEmployees.ToArray();
```

Ah hah! Now, we have generated content in our TreeViewItem. But, why was this necessary in the first place?

Comment: its a linq behavior. ToArray runs your query immediately, so you see your content

Comment: Have you tried add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` into get statement?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that: in the case of IEnumerable, you pass the expression to the ItemsSource, NOT a SOURCE. When you called: ToArray() which means that, it will execute the expression and return the actual data for the ItemsSource.

In summary, the first case: You tell the WPF how to get the ItemsSource. The second case: You pass the actual data source.